# Null Foreign Key (Springboot, Hibernate, Postman)

Tags: spring-boot, postman, spring-data-rest

I am using Springboot with Hibernate and I would like to save a new “post” using a POST request to my database. One thing that I would like to highlight is that I am using the dependency “spring-boot-starter-data-rest”.

Schema of the database (MySQL):
[image: Shema:]

Class User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", nullable = false)
    public int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user_id_fk")
    public Set<Post> posts;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="create_time")
    protected Date createTime;

    @Column(name="type")
    private String accountType;

    public User() {
        this.createTime = new java.util.Date();
    }

    public User(String email, String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, Date createTime, String accountType) {
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.createTime = createTime;
        this.accountType = accountType;
        this.createTime = new java.util.Date();
    }

    public User(int id, String email, String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, Date createTime, String accountType) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.createTime = createTime;
        this.accountType = accountType;
        this.createTime = new java.util.Date();
    }
```

Plus the Getters & Setters & toString().

Class Post:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="post")
public class Post implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    public int id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id_fk", nullable = false)
    public User user_id_fk;

    @Column(name="comment")
    private String comment;

    @Column(name="likes")
    private int likes;

    @Column(name="dislike")
    private int dislike;

    @Column(name="create_time")
    protected Date createTime;

    public Post() {
        this.createTime = new java.util.Date();
    }

    public Post(String comment, int likes, int dislike, User user_id_fk) {
        this.user_id_fk = user_id_fk;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.dislike = dislike;
        this.createTime = new java.util.Date();
    }

    public Post(int id, User user_id_fk, String comment, int likes, int dislike) {
        this.id = id;
        this.user_id_fk = user_id_fk;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.dislike = dislike;
        this.createTime = new java.util.Date();
    }
```

Plus the Getters & Setters & toString().

Post request (I'm using Postman to send the request):

```
{
"comment" : "This is a comment",
"likes" : 123,
"dislike" : 1,
"user_id_fk" :
[
    {
        "id" : 1
    }
]
}
```

In the request at the "user_id_fk" I tried with [ {"id" : 1 } ] and with { "id" : 1 } but the result was the same.

Issue:

When I am executing exactly the same code from my controller everything works are excepted. Bear in mind that I am using the dependency “spring-boot-starter-data-rest”.
Also, when I am executing the code without the `“optional = false”` and `“nullable = false”` is inserting the data into the database but the “user_id_fk” is null :(.

The error that I am getting:

```
not-null property references a null or transient value : com.citizen.citizen.entity.Post.user_id_fk; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.citizen.citizen.entity.Post.user_id_fk]
```

That means that the foreign key `("user_id_fk")` is null but should not be null.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you name your user user_id_fk? It's identified as the join column name, but why name the referenced entity that too? I've had spring get confused with naming collisions like this before.

Comment: I tried with another name for example "user" but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Does the user with id 1 already exist or are you trying to create it as well?

Comment: Yes ofc the user with ID 1 exists. Actually I have several users in the DB.  I also tried to send all the information for the user with ID 1 but again I havethe same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just remove the dependency "spring-boot-starter-data-rest" and I solved the issue by creating my custom rest and everything works. Kisses!

Comment: I am facing same issue , how did you get this to work ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships) article, you should make `user_id_fk` nullable and then:

1. Send POST to create User
2. Send second POST to create Post
3. Send PUT to create a relation between the two.

[This](https://reflectoring.io/relations-with-spring-data-rest/) article states the same.
And the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.association-resource) only mentions handling associations via association links.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand what you are saying but sending also a second request is not suitable for my use case. I would like to do in a single POST request if it is possible.

Comment: I added some more links, but from what I know about Spring Data REST, what you want is not possible. You need to write custom controllers for that.

Comment: Per comments, user already exists, so this should be possible with a single query.

Comment: Even if user exists , you still need two queries: one to create a post and another to assign the post to the user. Unless I'm misunderstaning something?

Comment: Yes as I can understand the doc you are correct. Anyway this workaround is not working for me I did all the REST custom without using the dependency “spring-boot-starter-data-rest”.